# How to make fake video source and make it non-downloadbale in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5-video

I'm working on an educational site that will plays online and offline videos.

I will forbid users from downloading the video from browser link and will force them to register in my app and then be able to download videos.

I solved the site visiting issue by creating a `FileContentResult` action and make this action login-needed.

But it has its own issues as a person will register in my app and enroll to class that contains video and download it then send it to his friends :)

Now I had searched many articles and probably in 90% of them I saw this is impossible.

But I have a sample site that contains videos and we can't download that with browser url.

This site is [Aparat](https://www.aparat.com/)

If you open it's videos you will see that src attribute value begins like `blob:some address` and you can't download it directly from browser with src attributes value.

How should I implement this in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: if you are displaying it to the user then there's always going to be a way... even when loading as a blob it still has to traverse the network so could be grabbed. the only way you are going to lock this content comprehensively is using DRM such as PlayReady or Widevine

Comment: Hmm Thank you for comment. this services are free?

Comment: no free DRM, so you'll have to weight up how valuable the content is vs the cost/effort of either obfuscating or going with a robust solution.